# Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

Working on what should be a simple call to a database. Selects the record corresponding to the current user and then executes some code based on the data retrieved. However, when it tries to query the database it returns "Data conversion failed. [ OLE DB status value (if known) = 2 ]". Any thoughts?

```
var db2 = Database.Open("DB2");
var progressCheck = "SELECT * FROM Progress WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;

foreach (var record in db2.Query(progressCheck)) {

Code here.

};
```

Comment: What is the value of WebSecurity.CurrentUserId?

Comment: @Rahul You were right! Can't believe I missed that. I was having a hard time understanding why it was trying to convert anything. Changed it and everything else runs beautifully! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the datatype for `ID` in your `progress` table? most probably `ID` in your table is a `varchar/char/nvarchar` column whereas `WebSecurity.CurrentUserId` is a `INT` type. so may be the problem. Change the type accordingly to resolve this.

So it's mainly failing in the below code line

```
"... WHERE ID=" + WebSecurity.CurrentUserId
```